Brightness is not changing and set at max in kali linux in HP Victus laptop
I have dual booted my HP Victus laptop with kali linux and windows 11 was pre-installed. The problem is that the brightness of the screen is not changing even with physical buttons and also not with brightness slider in linux. The brightness is stuck at max.
The screen just before booting of kali linux is shown in image and shows some bios error.

But this screen remains only for 2 seconds after which linux starts normally.
Steps I’ve Tried to Resolve the Brightness Issue on Linux:

Checked Brightness Keys
Verified whether the function keys (e.g., Fn + Brightness Keys) are working, but they had no effect on the brightness in Linux.

Manually Adjusted Brightness via Sysfs
Used the following command to manually adjust brightness by writing a value to /sys/class/backlight/:
echo 100 | sudo tee /sys/class/backlight/intel_backlight/brightness
However, this did not resolve the issue, and the brightness remained at maximum.

Verified if the issue might be related to drivers or kernel ACPI handling but can't find any solutions.

Tried Adding GRUB Boot Parameters
Edited /etc/default/grub and added the following boot parameters to improve ACPI handling:

acpi_backlight=vendor

acpi_osi=Linux

video.use_native_backlight=1
For example:


GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"
After editing, updated GRUB using:
sudo update-grub sudo reboot

Used xrandr to Adjust Brightness
Tried adjusting brightness using xrandr, which works at the software level. I ran:
xrandr --output eDP-1 --brightness 0.5
This successfully dimmed the screen but is only a temporary solution as it reduces gamma only and does not address the hardware backlight issue.

Updated Drivers and Kernel
Checked for updates to the kernel and graphics drivers:
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade

Installed Brightness Adjustment Tools
Installed brightnessctl, a tool to adjust brightness levels:
sudo apt install brightnessctl brightnessctl set 50%

Checked for ACPI Errors During Boot
Observed an "AE_NOT_FOUND" error during boot, which might indicate an ACPI-related issue affecting the backlight control. Ran the following command to investigate further:
dmesg | grep -i acpi

Explored BIOS/UEFI Settings.
Checked the BIOS/UEFI firmware to see if there were any settings related to brightness or ACPI handling. Found no specific options that resolved the issue.

Cross-Checked on Windows.
Confirmed that brightness control works fine in Windows, which indicates the hardware is functioning correctly, and the issue is specific to Linux.


Still until now even after after trying all of these steps, this issue is not resolved yet.

What have you tried and with what results? Do the buttons work if you live boot a user-friendly distribution like Debian or Ubuntu? Remember, Kali is not for novice users, but is a tool for a specific workflow.

Yes, now I updated the question with more info. Please help me with this problem.
